# Oracle Database change user password programmatically

Tags: vb.net, oracle, change-password

Is there any way to reset my Oracle database password programmatically using .net?

Or is there any sql query to reset my password?

Comment: ALTER USER theUser IDENTIFIED BY thePassword;

Answer (score 0):

To expand on @Glenn's comment, the `ALTER USER` statement is used to change passwords.  This statement can be used to change the password of the active user, or can be used to change any user's password if the active user has been granted the ALTER USER system privilege.  See the [Oracle documentation for ALTER USER here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_4003.htm).

Share and enjoy.